# SQL QUERY DATA FETCH IN CRYSTAL REPORT. it only fetch first row data

Tags: linq-to-sql, crystal-reports

```
var BikeOrder = (from s in dbobject.TblBikesOrders 
where s.BONo == searchint
select new {s.BOId,s.BONo,}).ToArray();
rptBikeOrder rptobject = new rptBikeOrder();
rptobject.SetDataSource(BikeOrder);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptobject;
```

how can i fix it. where s.BONo == searchint why not working

Answer (score 0):

Put the fields in the details section of the report